# SQL Convert one column with distinct values into several columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´using SQL Server and I don´t know how to approach this issue.
I have one table with 5.5M of records in the following form:

```
Device        Time             ValueID   Value   Voltage
------------------------------------------------------------
1   2014-03-08 22:50:00      AH1      90,0    90,000"

1   2014-03-08 22:50:00      AT1      5,5     5,500"

1   2014-03-08 22:50:00      PP1      0,0     0,000"

1   2014-03-08 22:50:00      WS1      0,0     0,000"

1   2014-03-08 22:50:00      WD1      270,0   270,000"

1   2014-03-08 22:50:00      SR1      0,0     0,000"

1   2014-03-08 23:49:00      ST1      8,288   2,993"
```

The column ValueID has 13 different datatypes and the column Value contains the measurement of the data type.

I need to create a table with the following form:

```
Device Time ValueID(AH1) ValueID(AT1) ValueID(PP1) etc...
------------------------------------------------------------
  1    xxxx   Value         Value          Value
```

I was trying to use INSERT in a new table with case statement but it does not work, ¿any different aproach? ¿Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: msysql or (MS)SQL-Server? Please remove unrelated tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can acheive the result by using Dynamic pivot

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop Table #temp

;WITH cte(Device,Time,ValueID,Value,Voltage)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'2014-03-08 22:50:00' ,'AH1', '90,0' ,  '90,000'   Union all
SELECT 1,'2014-03-08 22:50:00' ,'AT1', '5,5'  ,  '5,500'    Union all
SELECT 1,'2014-03-08 22:50:00' ,'PP1', '0,0'  ,  '0,000'    Union all
SELECT 1,'2014-03-08 22:50:00' ,'WS1', '0,0'  ,  '0,000'    Union all
SELECT 1,'2014-03-08 22:50:00' ,'WD1', '270,0',  '270,000'  Union all
SELECT 1,'2014-03-08 22:50:00' ,'SR1', '0,0'  ,  '0,000'    Union all
SELECT 1,'2014-03-08 23:49:00' ,'ST1', '8,288',  '2,993'  
)
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM CTE

Declare @Col nvarchar(max),
         @Sql nvarchar(max),
         @dynamicCol nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Col=STUFF((SELECT ', '+ ValueID 
From  #temp For XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

;With cte
AS
(
SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+  ValueID + ' AS '+QUOTENAME(' ValueID ('+ValueID+')')
From  #temp For XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS DynamicColumnames
)
SELECT @dynamicCol= DynamicColumnames from cte

SET @Sql='
SELECT Device,Time,'+ @dynamicCol +' From
(
SELECT Device,Time,ValueID,Value From
#temp
)AS Src
PIVOT 
(
MAX(Value) For ValueID IN ('+@Col+')
)
AS Pvt'

Print @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: Hmm it works but...how can I select all the table? Because this example is selecting only the first rows and I have 5.5M records

Comment: i wrote query as per your desired result , i cant imagine how would be your table structure

Comment: I was thinking to use some python scrypt but first I wanna try using SQL, actually this table is as you can see in the link, Im total begginer in SQL server so Im trying to understand your code, thanks a lot!

Comment: With refrence to your pic if it is the table on which your working my code will works though you n number records just replace my temp #TEMP table with your original table name and Run the code from comment the cte it is used for creating temp data result set only

Answer (score 3):

you can use pivot as below:

```
select Device, [Time], [AH1] as [Value(AH1)], [AT1] as [Value(AT1)]... from (
    select Device, [Time], ValueId, [Value] from Yourtable )
pivot (max([value]) for valueId in ([AH1],[AT1]...)) p
```

You can generate dynamic columns as below:

```
declare @cols varchar(max)
declare @fromcols varchar(max)
declare @query varchar(max)

select @cols = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(valueid) from #yourdevice group by valueid for xml path('')),1,1,'')
select @fromcols = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(valueid)+' as [Value('+ Valueid + ')]' from #yourdevice group by valueid for xml path('')),1,1,'')
--[AH1] as [Value(AH1)], [AT1] as [Value(AT1)]...

SET @query = 'select Device, [Time], ' + @fromcols + ' from ( ' + ' select Device, [Time], ValueId, [Value] from Yourtable ) a ' 
SET @Query = @query + ' pivot (max([value]) for valueId in (' + @cols + ')) p '

select @query --Execute below by uncommenting after checking the query
--exec sp_execute @query
```